# $ꓯaꓯb(f(a) = f(b) → a = b) ᴧ ꓯaꓯb(f(a) ≠ f(b) → a ≠ b)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Why does this hold true? I know this translates to "For all $a$ and $b$, if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $a = b$ and for all $a$ and $b$, if $f(a) \neq f(b)$, then $a \neq b$" Is my understanding correct? How can I express that this is true.

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your post to include some context; What are f,a, and b?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $f$ is a map $f:X\to Y$ between sets. Then
$$
f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b\, \forall a,b\in X
$$
is equivalent to $f$ being injective. This is not always the case: Take for instance $X=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=\{0\}$ and $f$ to be the constant map with $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

The condition
$$
f(a)\neq f(b) \implies a\neq b\, \forall a,b\in X
$$
however is equivalent to
$$
a=b \implies f(a)= f(b) \,\forall a,b\in X
$$
which is indeed always true for a map $f:X\to Y$. To see this recall the definition of a *map*. A map $f:X\to Y$ is a subset $S_f$ of $X\times Y$ such that
$$
\forall x \in X\, \exists!\,y\in Y:\, (x,y)\in S_f
$$
and we write $f(x)=y$ for $(x,y)\in S_f$. Now let $a,b\in X$ with $a=b$. Then by defintion we have $(a,f(a))\in S_f$ and $(b,f(b))\in S_f$. Since $a=b$ we also find $(a,f(b))\in S_f$. Then by the unqieness part of the defintion of a map we can conclude that $f(a)=f(b)$.